# How can i aggregate this schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

```
 items: [
            {
                item: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Items',
                    default: null,
                },
                variation: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Variation',
                    default: null,
                },
                addons: [
                    {
                        addons: {
                            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                            ref: 'Addons',
                            default: null,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                discount: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Discount',
                    default: null,
                },
                note: {
                    type: String,
                    lowercase: true,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null,
                },
                quantity: {
                    type: Number,
                    trim: true,
                    default: 1,
                },
                price: {
                    type: Number,
                    trim: true,
                    require: true,
                },
                amount: {
                    type: Number,
                    trim: true,
                    require: true,
                },
            },
        ],
```

i have try many solution, can some help me out with this problem.
i have try many solution, can some help me out with this problem.
i have try many solution, can some help me out with this problem.
i have try many solution, can some help me out with this problem.